# Get a value from an multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a variable called $authors_id that gives me an array of 3 users, and inside each user theres an ID i need to call to be able to get their pics.
Here:

[image: Database image]

i have tried calling it like this:

```
$authors_img = $authors_id[0]['data]['ID'];
```

But it doesnt work. Can someone point me out what im doing wrong?

Comment: `$authors_id[0]->data->ID;` as `WP_User` and `data` are objects not arrays

Comment: it is an array of object you will need `$authors_id[0]->data->ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is:

```
$authors_img = $authors_id[0]->data->ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $authors_id[0]->data->ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is

```
$authors_img = $authors_id[0]->data->ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed one single quates in your code :

```
$authors_img = $authors_id[0]['data]['ID'];
```

should be :

```
$authors_img = $authors_id[0]['data']['ID'];
```